# Informal proof of diagonal lemma

Tags: logic

I am reading [this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC9fw.png) of the diagonal lemma
and I do not understand what is happening here. Could you informally explain what is the strategy here? I would appreciate it if you went step by step. I am aware of [this](http://rkheck.frege.org/philosophy/pdf/notes/DiagonalLemma.pdf) informal exposition, but I don't think it explains the proof itself.

Comment: Could you expand on which part of the proof you don't understand?  That would help others explain it. There's not really much of an informal strategy, except "construct the thing the theorem says must exist". The construction is hard to discover - it's the kind of proof that you simply check step by step.

Comment: See also the post [proving-and-understanding-the-fixed-point-lemma-diagonal-lemma-in-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443617/proving-and-understanding-the-fixed-point-lemma-diagonal-lemma-in-logic-used)

Answer (score 1):

You could try §47 of the notes Gödel Without Tears, which is still rather terse buy the notation might be a bit more helpful.

https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/gwt/GWT2f.pdf